# Problems creating ConvertString function

Tags: c++

The following is the code I did until now:

```
int mod_int;
int i=0;
if (isalpha(input_string[i]))
{
    int start = 65;

    if (islower(input_string[i]))

        int start = 97;

return ConvertString(input_string, mod_int=(((int)input_string[i] - start + mod_int) % 26) + start);

        else cout << input_string[i];

            string ConvertString(string input_string, int mod_int) {
                for (char& c : input_string) {
                    if (std::isupper(c)) {
                        c = 'A' + (c - 'A' + mod_int) % 26;
                    }
                    else if (std::islower(c)) {
                        c = 'a' + (c - 'a' + mod_int) % 26;
                    }
                }
                return input_string;
```

I Keep on getting the message "Expected unqualified-id" at the third line. Why do I keep on getting this message? What does it mean?

Also I'm supposed to write a ConvertString function and I'm having trouble knowing how to create the function. The description is the following:

Write a function (ConvertString) that modifies the input string input_string by
substitutes each alphabetical character by a character, which is mod_int positions down the alphabet. For example, given mod_int = 1, ‘a’ is substituted by ‘b’, ‘b’ is substituted by ‘c’, and so on until ‘z’ is substituted by ‘a’. Therefore, calling ConvertString with input_string = “abcd”, and mod_int = 1, should return
“bcde”. Other characters (such as %, *, &, ….) remain the same. The function returns the converted string.

So basically, when
input_string= `Hello`
and
int_mod= `4`
int_string= `Lipps`

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is `mod_int` declared before using?

Comment: it gives me this message for the second and third line so im guessing that's not the problem

Comment: If it's not declared then that's the problem.

Comment: The formatting on this question is a little bit scrambled, and I can't make heads or tails of the code. Is the return statement under the `if` condition?

Comment: I wrote: int mod_int;

Comment: But it didn't change anything

Comment: I dont understand... what's the return statement?

Comment: Unrelated to your error, but I think `if (isalpha(input_string[x]))` should be `if (isalpha(input_string[i]))`, that is, the variable should be `i`, not `x`. And also in some other places (basically all from that point onwards).

Comment: oh okay im gonna change that right away thanks!

Comment: Something is wrong with this: for (int i=0; i<input_string.length(); i++)
It keeps on saying "Expected unqualified ID"

Comment: Prefer to use character constants instead of the ASCII value, as it makes your code more readable.  For example, replace 65 with 'A'.

Comment: Oh ok, what should I replace 97 with? @ThomasMatthews

Comment: Think.  Why are you using 97?  What does it represent?  You could look it up in an ASCII chart.

Comment: Oh ok got it, its for 'a'. @ThomasMatthews
Btw can you help me out with the function ConvertString that im supposed to do? im having difficulties creating it i don't understand it very well im still really new to coding!

Comment: No.  I don't want to repeat what is already posted on the internet.  Search StackOverflow for "c++ caesar cipher", you can search the internet as well. A plethora of examples exist.

Comment: Alright thank you for your help.